# How to make a group with multiple column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I want to repeat first row first column value in every row in a particular column like a group. Please let me know how i will do it?

```
Table

    Id - Title 
    1  - ABC1
    2  - ABC2
    3  - ABC3
    4  - ABC4
    5  - ABC5
```

I want result like this in a simple select query, Please dont use variable for it means storing first row value in a variable,

Resultant Table

```
Table

Id - Title - Group
1  - ABC1  - 1
2  - ABC2  - 1
3  - ABC3  - 1
4  - ABC4  - 1
5  - ABC5  - 1
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean... Where is `Group` coming from?

Comment: Group is the new column which i want resultant from select query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query will be helpful to get expected result.

```
SELECT Id, Title, (SELECT TOP 1 Id FROm Table ORDER BY ID) AS [Group]  FROM Table
```

Comment: I tick it as correct but for you information if records are increase suppose 10000 the it will decrease the execute time

Comment: The use of `TOP` without an `order by` should be discouraged unless you really, really know what you are doing.  This can return different values on different executions.

Answer (score 1):

USE THE QUERY: (ORDER BY ID ASC will make sure that the first ID will selected always even if there is a change of order in ID.)

```
SELECT Id, Title,
       (SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM Table ORDER BY ID ASC) 
AS [Group]  FROM Table
```

Answer (score -3):

Something like:

SELECT Id, Title, 1 AS [Group]  FROM Table

If the Group value is different, then we need to know where that value is coming from.